# Xamarin form -calling variable from other .cs file

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am doing a quiz game in Xamarin Forms, and for the score function, if the user got a correct answer, I want 1 to be added to the score. But in my case even with the correct answer, the score is not increased.

I am also trying to bind to the "score" variable to a label. I want to know if I use correct code or not.

**Button**

```cs
private void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string answer = this.answer.Text;
    string canswer = "correct";

    if (answer != null)
    {
        string ranswer = answer.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

        if (ranswer.ToLower() == canswer)
        {
            DisplayAlert("GoodJob", "You got the correct answer", "OK");
            bindingModel b = new bindingModel();
            b.score++;
          
            (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            DisplayAlert("Unfortunately", "Your answer is wrong", "OK");
            (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class bindingModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int displayScore => Score;
    public int score = 0;

    void OnPropertyChanged(int score)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(score.ToString()));
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get => score;
        set
        {
            if (score != value)
            {
                score = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(score);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

**Model**

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding Score}"/>
```

Comment: your `submit_Clicked` is creating a **new instance** of `bindingModel` instead of the instance that already exists on the page

Comment: @Jason thankyou for the response, may i ask wha tis the correct way the use the existed instance. im new at programming

Answer (score 0):

in your page constructor, keep a reference to your VM

```
bindingModel VM;

// this is your constructor, the name will match your page name
public MyPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.BindingContext = VM = new bindingModel();

  ...
}
```

then in your event handler, you do NOT need to create a new `bindingModel`

```
// update the Count on the VM
VM.Count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

There's two things broken here:

1. You are re-initializing your ViewModel instead of referencing the same instance
2. You are passing the wrong value into `PropertyChangedEventArgs`

#### 1. Referencing the View Model

You are re-initializing the ViewModel every time by calling `bindingModel b = new bindingModel();`

Lets initialize the ViewModel once, store it as a field, set it as the `BindingContext` for our `ContentPage`, and reference that field in `submit_Clicked`

```cs
public partial class QuizPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly bindingModel _bindingModel;

    public QuizPage()
    {
        _bindingModel = new bindingModel();
        BindingContext = _bindingModel;
    }

    private async void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string answer = this.answer.Text;
        string canswer = "correct";

        Button button = (Button)sender;
    
        if (answer != null)
        {
            string ranswer = answer.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    
            if (ranswer.ToLower() == canswer)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("GoodJob", "You got the correct answer", "OK");
                _bindingModel.score++;
    
                button.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Unfortunately", "Your answer is wrong", "OK");
                button.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. PropertyChangedEventArgs

You need to pass in the name of the property to `PropertyChangedEventArgs`.

They way `PropertyChanged` works is that it announces the name of the property that has changed. In this case, it needs to broadcast that the `Score` property has changed.

Let's use `nameof(Score)` to pass in the string `"Score"` to `PropertyChangedEventArgs`:

```cs
void OnScorePropertyChanged()
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(displayScore)));
}

public int Score
{
    get => score;
    set
    {
        if (score != value)
        {
            score = value;
            OnScorePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to ask how could I save the value to the variable ? since I have around 10 questions and on each question, I need to increment the variable if the user gives the correct answer.

Comment: @JUSTINCHUA The value of score increased every time the user give the right answer, the value did saved in the score.